# SafeArea not working for a Form displaying an overflow menu or a Dialog

Tags: codenameone

I've noticed on iPhone Xr with iOS 13.3.1 that the new support for SafeArea (https://www.codenameone.com/blog/safe-areas.html) is not working in (at least) a few situations.

When `setSafeArea(true)` is set for a `Form` it displays correctly within the safe area. But when the Form opens the `Toolbar` overflow menu or displays a `Dialog`, the `Form` is immediately expanded to fill the entire screen, just as if the safeArea was not activated. When the overflow menu or dialog closes, the Form is redisplayed correctly within the safe area. This gives a very jumpy/jittery experience.

I believe I've seen the same issue in other situations, so the problem may be more general than just these two situations.

Is this is a bug or am I not using the safeArea correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug. Please file an issue [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/).

Overflow is implemented as a dialog so this seems to be a problem with dialogs. Dialogs paint the background form in a unique way. It isn't the actual Form behind but rather a "fake" painting of the form. This painting process needs to take the safe area into account.

Comment: Thanks, I reported the issue and it is fixed since.